# A basic doubt on the definition of order of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, optimization

In the book of Luenberger, I see the following definition of order of convergence: it is defined as the supremum of the non-negative numbers $p$  satisfying $$0 \leq \limsup_{k\to\infty} \frac{|r_{k+1} - r^*|}{|r_{k} - r^*|^p}\lt \infty$$ where the sequence $\{r_k\}$ converges to $r^*$.

In Wikipedia page, it is defined as the following :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence. How the two are equivalent is not clear to me. Also it looks like that the Wikipedia page tells that "quadratic convergence is a kind of linear convergence."  Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: try to show that if there exist $q,\mu>0$ such that
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{|x_{k+1}-L|}{|x_k-L|^q}=\mu$$
then for all $0<p<q<r$ one has
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{|x_{k+1}-L|}{|x_k-L|^p}= 0\quad ;\quad \lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{|x_{k+1}-L|}{|x_k-L|^r}=\infty$$

**Added**: To answer the questions in comments, if such $q,\mu$ exist, $q$ is said to be the order of convergence; the hint was intended to show why the order of convergence is well-defined. Indeed the sequence converges faster the larger $q$ is, if it exists.

However, we can't always find such an order. For example, if $x_n = n!^{-1}$ then for all $q>0$ one has
$$\log\frac{|x_{k+1}-0|}{|x_k-0|^q} = q\log(k!)-\log((k+1)!) = (q-1)\log(k!) - \log(k+1),$$
which tends to $-\infty$ for $0<q\leq 1$ and to $\infty$ for $1<q$, implying that $\frac{|x_{k+1}-0|}{|x_k-0|^q}$ tends to $0,\infty$ respectively, but never to $\mu>0$.

Comment: why is it lim sup ?

Comment: Is this correct that order of convergence $p$ means that in the limit error at the $k+1$-th iteration will be less than $p$-th power of the error at the $k$-th iteration. So, the higher $p$ is, we have faster convergence.

Comment: Y: yes I am able to prove it. But, is there any gurrantee that such a $q$ and $\mu >0$ exist.

Comment: @user96000 did the edit answer all your questions?